# Where does Xenserver store local VMs

Tags: virtual-machines, xenserver

My xenserver crashed a few months ago, I haven't been able to retrieve the VMs that were on it.

There was nothing special about the installation, I think it was all standard.

Is there a way to recover the VMs on it? It won't start up. I have tried searching for them on the hard-drive but I haven't managed to find anything. Does anyone know the location where they are stored on the hard-drive?

Comment: `find / -iname "*vmname*"` is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first stop should be reading Citrix's [How to Export a Virtual Machine to an External USB Drive](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX120520).

It will be best to try and recover the DomU's using the procedures linked - by booting the Dom0 and using `xe` to export the domU:

```
# xe vm-list
# xe vm-export vm=myVM filename=myVM-export.xva
```

If your dom0 is smoking wreckage this gets substantially harder. I don't think you can boot a LiveCD and scrape the VMs off the disks - at the very least we need to know what kind of storage you are using. You could try doing something like re-installing XenServer while leaving the VMs intact ([How to Reinstall XenServer and Preserve Virtual Machines on a Local Disk](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX120962)).

Answer (score 5):

VM hard drives are stored in /var/run/sr-mount/ will contain folders containing your local/remote repositories. Each folder has name = UUID of the storage repository
Unfortunately, this won't help you restoring your VMs, as you need backups for restoring them. Use xe vm-export ... command from the comment #1.